# How to install on System 32 folder using an x86 compilation with Wix

Tags: wix, wix3.5, wix3.6, wix3.7

I'm building an x86 compilation of a [Wix](http://wixtoolset.org/) project.

For some technical reasons, I need to copy some .dlls in system 32 folder. To do so, I wrote the following lines:

```
// In an external .wxs file
<?define System32Dir= "C:\Windows\System32" />

<Component Id="cmp32bits"  Directory="System32Dir" Guid="*">
    <Condition>NOT VersionNT64</Condition>
    <File Id="file32bits" KeyPath="yes" Source="mypathtothefile" />
</Component>

<Component Id="cmp64bits"  Directory="System32Dir" Guid="*">
    <Condition>VersionNT64</Condition>
    <File Id="file32bits" KeyPath="yes" Source="mypathtothefile" />
</Component>
```

But then it fails as System32Dir contains slashes, points...

Following [this](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/folder-paths.html) guide, if I use the `SystemFolder` for x86 systems and the `System32Folder` for x64 systems, when I install the product, for 64 bits machines the .dlls are installed in `SysWOW64`. I understand that, if I compile the Wix project in x86, the `System32Folder` will be translated the same for 64 bits systems.

That's the reason why I came to hand write the "C:\Windows\System32", but it's not working yet.

The question and important point is, **how to copy anything in C:\Windows\System32** directory if I'm installing an x86 project into a 64 bits machine?

Thanks a lot.

**EDIT:** Added a `CustomAction` but could not make it work.

```
 <CustomAction Id="CopyToSystem32" ExeCommand="[INSTALLFOLDER]copy.bat" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER" Execute="deferred" Return="asyncWait" />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="CopyToSystem32" After="InstallFiles" >NOT Installed</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Where the `.bat` file looks like this:

```
copy 64bits.txt C:\Windows\System32
```

But actually, I can't make the `CustomAction` work...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't officially install 64-bit components from a 32-bit package:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367451(v=vs.85).aspx

and Windows will typically keep redirecting you to 32-bit folders.

I'd examine the reasons why you are being asked to install Dlls to the 64-bit system folder from a 32-bit install. If they are 64-bit Dlls then you potentially need a separate 64-bit install:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2008/01/15/different-packages-are-required-for-different-processor-architectures.aspx

and if they are 32-bit Dlls then an app that requires them in the 64-bit system folder needs some re-architecting to get up to date with 64-bit systems.

Comment: Sad conclusion (the same I was afraid of after some investigation)... but I understand it.

Answer (score -1):

I did the below things in my installer for this requirement.

Ship files to somewhere in installation location and later copy those files to “C:\Windows\System32” using DTF deferred custom action.

Comment: See my edit please. I tried to do so, but I can't make it work... Seems like a solution, but still doesn't work for me.

Comment: It's a bad idea to use custom actions for things MSI supports natively.

Comment: @BobArnson Yes. I agree with you. But this is like some exception cases.

Comment: @Sonhja Your code seems to work for me. Could you please share complete sample what you tried? I will take a look.